# Python for loop: Looping over hierarchical data

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I would like to analyse data with the following structure:

```
parent transaction

     child transaction A     
                  child transaction AA                       
                  child transaction AB
                  child transaction AC

     child transaction B
                  child transaction BA
                  child transaction BB
                  child transaction BC
```

In this structure the child transactions (e.g. child transaction AA) may have children as well, I would like to go down to as many levels of depth as possible and ideally even define the max depth through a variable (in the code below the variable depth_level)
How can I do this with a for loop? My issue currently is that execution stops after finishing one branch of the tree (for example child transaction A)

My code is currently structured like this:

```
start_address=callAddress('bc1qn3gwc49e02kkd2t8svpcmg5hlvtaacvl79wae0')
transaction_targets=analyseTransaction(start_address)
for j in transaction_targets:
    result=callAddress(j)
    inner_transaction_targets=analyseTransaction(result)
    compileAddresses(compiled_receiver_addresses,inner_transaction_targets)
    for i in inner_transaction_targets:
        result=callAddress(i)
        inner_out_addr=analyseTransaction(result)
        compileAddresses(compiled_receiver_addresses,inner_out_addr)
        depth_level=depth_level+1
        print(depth_level)
        if depth_level>50:
            print('Maximum depth reached.')
            break
```

The "analyseTransaction" function returns a list of transactions, i.e. the child transactions in the overview above. The function "compileAddresses" gathers all recorded transaction addresses in a list.
I would like the loop to execute downwards until a depth of x(identified by the variable "depth_level") and then go to the next branch (i.e. child transacction B).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You do not provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) nor a detailed expected output. As I currently understand your problem, you are mixing up **depth** with **width**. Your code seems to indicate that the child-child transactions (`AA` for example) may have childrens themselves, if that is indeed the case firstly the data structure you gave failed to mention it, and secondly nesting for loops won't solve your problem, you need proper **recursion**.

Comment: @Lenormju sorry for not including all needed info!indeed the children have children themselves
How would I approach this topic using recursion?

Comment: What @Joffan explains : recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't handle this comfortably with a fixed looping control like `for`. There are ways you could use `while` if you were loading (& perhaps unloading) information from a list. The natural fit though is to use a recursive call to deal with each level of structure as you encounter it, with a state parameter to control depth.

Something like:

```py
def traverse(target, depth):
    result=callAddress(target)
    inner_transaction_targets=analyseTransaction(result)
    compileAddresses(compiled_receiver_addresses,inner_transaction_targets)
    if depth > 0:
        for inner in inner_transaction_targets:
            traverse(inner, depth-1)
    else:
        pass  # not sure what you want to do at max depth; just leave it?


for j in transaction_targets:
    traverse(j,max_depth)
```